# conflit version java :UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Tags: java, server

I created a runnable jar with 1.5.0.07 java version, I deployed it to a server which runs with the same version of java, 
I had two methods which use the same `spring jdbc` , when I run the jar in the server the first method works fine but the second return this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at com.auto.dao.ContractsDAO.getContractsList(ContractsDAO.java:46)
    at com.auto.main.AutoReactivation.main(AutoReactivation.java:88)
```

When I googled this problem, I find that's a problem of  conflict different Java JDK but I don't get it because I have the same version of java in my project and in the server.

Comment: This can't be complex. Either you're running on a java version that's not compatible or one of your classes (could be third-party libraries) was compiled for a more recent java version.

Comment: There was no version `1.5.0.07`  There was a Java 5.0 update 7 released in 2007. which had an internal version `1.5.0_07`  Given this version is more than a decade old, I would suspect a bug and use a new update. The last public update of Java 5.0 was "update 85" which I imagine fixed a few bugs.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I can't update the java version to 85 in the server

Comment: @PeterLawrey also I didn't find `update 85` , did you mean `update 22` ?

Comment: @ernest_k I used a java classes from a web service, in which I don't know the version of java , do you think that the problem in these classes ?

Comment: Good point, updates after 22 were not public.

Comment: Newer versions of Java tell you what the bad magic number was which gives you a clue so I would say something is very wrong if it cannot, but given this is more than 10 years old, it could be that the error message wasn't very good then.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I deploy it in a server which compiled with     java 1.8 and it works fine

Comment: @mak_doni so the class was most likely built for a version after Java 5.